# How to set values in the session session prior to making a request in tests

Tags: session, testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have actions in my Phoenix / Plug application that have different behaviour depending on the state of the session. I wish to test this behaviour, but I am unsure how to set the session prior to making a request.

Here is an example of what I wish to be able to do:

```
test "GET index when not signed", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = get conn, item_path(conn, :index)
  assert html_response(conn, 302)
end

test "GET index when signed in", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = conn |> put_session(:current_user, 1)
  conn = get conn, item_path(conn, :index)
  assert html_response(conn, 200)
end
```

Note the attempt to set the session in the second test.

This does not work, and I get an error message like so:

```
** (ArgumentError) session not fetched, call fetch_session/2
```

But I cannot use `fetch_session/1`, as the session plug has not been configured here.

I could hit actions that set the session state I need, but then I have add testing hooks to my production code, which seems less than ideal.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: You need to call `Conn.fetch_session`. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31983168/2697183) for implementation

Comment: Vote to close since this is a duplicate.