# Assign current user in session for tests

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have found similar answers to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983077/how-can-i-set-session-in-setup-when-i-test-phoenix-action-which-need-user-id-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137242/how-to-use-connection-with-session-in-phoenix), but it does not seem to be working.

I am having trouble assigning the `current_user` to the session when testing. My tests are set up like this

```
setup do
  %User{
    id: 123456,
    name: "MyName",
    email: "abc@gmail.com",
    password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("password")
  } |> Repo.insert

 {:ok, user: Repo.get(User, 123456) }
end
```

and my test is

```
test "renders index.html on /coping-strategy", %{user: user} do
  conn = conn
      |> assign(:current_user, user)
      |> get(coping_strategy_path(conn, :index))
  assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Coping strategies"
end
```

When I inspect the conn here, `current_user` has been correctly assigned to `user`. However, when I inspect the conn in my controller during testing, `current_user` is always `nil`. I tried using `build_conn` as well, but it is still nil.

Here is the controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  user_id = conn.assigns.current_user.id
  coping_strategies = Post
                      |> Post.get_coping_strategies(user_id)
                      |> Repo.all
  render conn, "index.html", coping_strategies: coping_strategies
end
```

If I try to assign something other than current_user, then it shows up when I inspect the conn in the controller. So if I added in `|> assign(:stuff, "test")` in the test, then I have `stuff: "test"` in assigns in the conn. If I change `current_user` to `current_user2` in the test and in the controller, it works because current_user2 updates and is passed along as I expect it to be.

Is there a reason I cannot assign the current user like this and why it is always nil? Are there any steps I am missing to do this for current_user in particular?

**Edit**

Here's where current_user is being set in the auth plug

```
def call(conn, repo) do
  user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)
  user = user_id && repo.get(Healthlocker.User, user_id)
  assign(conn, :current_user, user)
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that assigns `current_user` in your app (authentication plug?)? You're probably setting it to `nil` even if it's already set.

Comment: @Dogbert that looks like it. user is `nil` when I'm running the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're directly setting `:current_user` in `assigns` in the tests, you need to skip fetching the user from the session's `:user_id` if `assigns` contains `:current_user` in the auth plug:

```
def call(conn, repo) do
  if conn.assigns[:current_user] do
    conn
  else
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)
    user = user_id && repo.get(Healthlocker.User, user_id)
    assign(conn, :current_user, user)
  end
end
```